# How to send automated email in ruby on rails using whenever gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm making a project in rails where i want to add automated email functionality.I choosed whenever gem for that purpose.I created rake task separately for sending email.

email_tasks.rake

```
desc 'send digest email'
task send_digest_email: :environment do
  # ... set options if any
   InterviewScheduleMailer.sample_email(@interview_schedule).deliver!
end
```

schedule  file

```html
set :environment, :development
# Example:
#
# set :output, "/path/to/my/cron_log.log"
#
 every :friday, :at => '3:52 am' do  
  rake 'send_digest_email'
end

every :friday, :at => '4:01 pm' do  
   runner "InterviewSchedule.sample_email"
 end
```

my email only goes when i run bundle exec send_digest_email.

i want the email to be delivered to all the employees based on date.For example who is having birthday.So email should go automatically at 12 a.m.

Comment: sample_email is the name of the action which i specified in ActionMailer.

Comment: Have you tried it in production? I can never make whenever work in development Also why are you setting the environment to development in schedule.rb ?

Comment: Ill try that in development and update the status...Thanx....

Comment: I tried to do that in production environment,still i'm unable to send email at the time i specified.Email only goes when i run bundle exec rake digest_email and it goes as many times i run that command.I want the email to go automatically.

Comment: Then at wht environment I may set my schedule.rb to?????

Comment: I don't think you need to set the environment in shedule.rb, in fact if you set it to development, it would not get triggered in production

Comment: So what I should do now... In order to let my email to send automatically ag 12 a.m.....! Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on *nix-type OS have you update the cron tab to have whenever job changes ?

you can run following command to see contents of the crontab

```
crontab -l
```

you will probably see your crontab contents similar to below

```
30 23 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/xyz/myproject/Nov-02/myproject && myproject_bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=development send_email'
```

you can do following to update your crontab with the whenever schedule

```
whenever -w
```

more details here [crontab with rails](http://www.sitepoint.com/schedule-cron-jobs-whenever-gem/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply....yes i updated the crontab by using $ whenever --update-crontab and also seen the list of cron job.But still i'm unable to send email at particular interval which i specified in schedule file.when i rub bundle exec send_digest_email.Only at that tym email goes and it goes as many tym i run that command.

Comment: do you have any link or any other gem from which i can achieve this functionality.

Comment: have you tried see logs ? what does your crontab -l looks like ?

Comment: 0 23 * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /Users/xyz/myproject/Nov-02/myproject && myproject_bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I use the scheduler, it does not work in development but works in production

```
# add ,roles: [:app] if you are using capistrano for deployment
every 1.day, :at => '7:06 am' do
  command "some linux commands"
end

# add ,roles: [:app] if you are using capistrano for deployment
every 1.day, at: '07:00 am' do
  runner "DailyMailer.log_export_email.deliver_later"
end
# Learn more: http://github.com/javan/whenever
```

You may also try to trigger the mailer directly but I would suggest to check the activejob queue adapter set in your config/application.rb

I use sidekiq for activejob queues and deliver_later method for sending the email. This way process runs in background.

You may need to use a different method for your mailer based on your queue adapter.

Hope it helps

Comment: Bro....will you please provide me code or any refferel link....it will be great....

Comment: Sure I'll try to help. Which production environment are you using? Any linux server or Heroku? Also how are you handling the deployment? Are you using any deployment tools such as Capistrano or are you just pushing the repo to the production?

Comment: If you are using heroku, you don't need whenever gem, you can use Heroku Scheduler add-on for free and run any rake task you want quite easily.